# NGINX proxy_pass IP Change

Tags: nginx

I have done an IP address change due to an update and for some reason my proxy_pass is still retaining the old IP is there a way to clear it?

**Code:**

```
  location /page/ {
      include cloudflare;
      add_header Access-Control-Allow-Origin subdomain.domain.com;
      proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $remote_addr;
      proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto https;
      proxy_pass http://subdomain.domain.com/;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can run `service nginx reload` to reload the nginx configuration if you're using systemd. If you didn't just make an update to the config file its probably DNS retaining that old IP.